# Memory leak in static shared_ptr

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, shared-ptr

I'm getting for a some reason which I can not understand a memory leak I think during destruction of a static `shared_ptr`. The program currently runs perfectly, until the end, however after the last return statement I get:

```
Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

I ran Valgrind on the program and got:

```
==4185== Invalid read of size 4
==4185==    at 0x4559DC: __gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add_single(int*, int) (atomicity.h:67)
==4185==    by 0x455AC5: __gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add_dispatch(int*, int) (atomicity.h:84)
==4185==    by 0x470D6C: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:141)
==4185==    by 0x46AB12: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:546)
==4185==    by 0x4A1B03: std::__shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:781)
==4185==    by 0x4A1B41: std::shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry>::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:93)
==4185==    by 0x78F45E9: __cxa_finalize (cxa_finalize.c:56)
==4185==    by 0x5B10E62: ??? (in /home/alex/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/metadiff-core-dac47eeb/dac47eeb/Debug/libmd_core.so)
==4185==    by 0x4010739: _dl_fini (dl-fini.c:252)
==4185==    by 0x78F4258: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:82)
==4185==    by 0x78F42A4: exit (exit.c:104)
==4185==    by 0x78D9ECB: (below main) (libc-start.c:321)
==4185==  Address 0x7c95ab8 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 96 free'd
==4185==    at 0x4C2C171: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:575)
==4185==    by 0x4A8663: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::deallocate(std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:110)
==4185==    by 0x4A794E: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::deallocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:377)
==4185==    by 0x4AA267: std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_destroy() (shared_ptr_base.h:417)
==4185==    by 0x470E21: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:161)
==4185==    by 0x46AB12: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:546)
==4185==    by 0x4A1B03: std::__shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:781)
==4185==    by 0x4A1B41: std::shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry>::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:93)
==4185==    by 0x78F4258: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:82)
==4185==    by 0x78F42A4: exit (exit.c:104)
==4185==    by 0x78D9ECB: (below main) (libc-start.c:321)
==4185==  Block was alloc'd at
==4185==    at 0x4C2B145: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:333)
==4185==    by 0x4A85AE: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:104)
==4185==    by 0x4A788F: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:351)
==4185==    by 0x4A6A01: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, md::sym::Registry*, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry> const&) (shared_ptr_base.h:499)
==4185==    by 0x4A59FB: std::__shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry> const&) (shared_ptr_base.h:957)
==4185==    by 0x4A44C9: std::shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry>::shared_ptr<std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry> const&) (shared_ptr.h:316)
==4185==    by 0x4A353D: std::shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry> std::allocate_shared<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>>(std::allocator<md::sym::Registry> const&) (shared_ptr.h:598)
==4185==    by 0x4A1FD8: std::shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry> std::make_shared<md::sym::Registry>() (shared_ptr.h:614)
==4185==    by 0x4A02E0: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) (base.cpp:10)
==4185==    by 0x4A034B: _GLOBAL__sub_I_base.cpp (base.cpp:206)
==4185==    by 0x4B7BDC: __libc_csu_init (in /media/hdd/work/metadiff/metadiff-core/build/try)
==4185==    by 0x78D9E54: (below main) (libc-start.c:246)
==4185== 
==4185== Invalid read of size 4
==4185==    at 0x4559E5: __gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add_single(int*, int) (atomicity.h:68)
==4185==    by 0x455AC5: __gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add_dispatch(int*, int) (atomicity.h:84)
==4185==    by 0x470D6C: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:141)
==4185==    by 0x46AB12: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:546)
==4185==    by 0x4A1B03: std::__shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:781)
==4185==    by 0x4A1B41: std::shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry>::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:93)
==4185==    by 0x78F45E9: __cxa_finalize (cxa_finalize.c:56)
==4185==    by 0x5B10E62: ??? (in /home/alex/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/metadiff-core-dac47eeb/dac47eeb/Debug/libmd_core.so)
==4185==    by 0x4010739: _dl_fini (dl-fini.c:252)
==4185==    by 0x78F4258: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:82)
==4185==    by 0x78F42A4: exit (exit.c:104)
==4185==    by 0x78D9ECB: (below main) (libc-start.c:321)
==4185==  Address 0x7c95ab8 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 96 free'd
==4185==    at 0x4C2C171: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:575)
==4185==    by 0x4A8663: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::deallocate(std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:110)
==4185==    by 0x4A794E: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::deallocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:377)
==4185==    by 0x4AA267: std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_destroy() (shared_ptr_base.h:417)
==4185==    by 0x470E21: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:161)
==4185==    by 0x46AB12: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:546)
==4185==    by 0x4A1B03: std::__shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:781)
==4185==    by 0x4A1B41: std::shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry>::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:93)
==4185==    by 0x78F4258: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:82)
==4185==    by 0x78F42A4: exit (exit.c:104)
==4185==    by 0x78D9ECB: (below main) (libc-start.c:321)
==4185==  Block was alloc'd at
==4185==    at 0x4C2B145: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:333)
==4185==    by 0x4A85AE: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:104)
==4185==    by 0x4A788F: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:351)
==4185==    by 0x4A6A01: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, md::sym::Registry*, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry> const&) (shared_ptr_base.h:499)
==4185==    by 0x4A59FB: std::__shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry> const&) (shared_ptr_base.h:957)
==4185==    by 0x4A44C9: std::shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry>::shared_ptr<std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry> const&) (shared_ptr.h:316)
==4185==    by 0x4A353D: std::shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry> std::allocate_shared<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>>(std::allocator<md::sym::Registry> const&) (shared_ptr.h:598)
==4185==    by 0x4A1FD8: std::shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry> std::make_shared<md::sym::Registry>() (shared_ptr.h:614)
==4185==    by 0x4A02E0: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) (base.cpp:10)
==4185==    by 0x4A034B: _GLOBAL__sub_I_base.cpp (base.cpp:206)
==4185==    by 0x4B7BDC: __libc_csu_init (in /media/hdd/work/metadiff/metadiff-core/build/try)
==4185==    by 0x78D9E54: (below main) (libc-start.c:246)
==4185== 
==4185== Invalid write of size 4
==4185==    at 0x4559F0: __gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add_single(int*, int) (atomicity.h:68)
==4185==    by 0x455AC5: __gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add_dispatch(int*, int) (atomicity.h:84)
==4185==    by 0x470D6C: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:141)
==4185==    by 0x46AB12: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:546)
==4185==    by 0x4A1B03: std::__shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:781)
==4185==    by 0x4A1B41: std::shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry>::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:93)
==4185==    by 0x78F45E9: __cxa_finalize (cxa_finalize.c:56)
==4185==    by 0x5B10E62: ??? (in /home/alex/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/metadiff-core-dac47eeb/dac47eeb/Debug/libmd_core.so)
==4185==    by 0x4010739: _dl_fini (dl-fini.c:252)
==4185==    by 0x78F4258: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:82)
==4185==    by 0x78F42A4: exit (exit.c:104)
==4185==    by 0x78D9ECB: (below main) (libc-start.c:321)
==4185==  Address 0x7c95ab8 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 96 free'd
==4185==    at 0x4C2C171: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:575)
==4185==    by 0x4A8663: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::deallocate(std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:110)
==4185==    by 0x4A794E: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::deallocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:377)
==4185==    by 0x4AA267: std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_destroy() (shared_ptr_base.h:417)
==4185==    by 0x470E21: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:161)
==4185==    by 0x46AB12: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:546)
==4185==    by 0x4A1B03: std::__shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:781)
==4185==    by 0x4A1B41: std::shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry>::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:93)
==4185==    by 0x78F4258: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:82)
==4185==    by 0x78F42A4: exit (exit.c:104)
==4185==    by 0x78D9ECB: (below main) (libc-start.c:321)
==4185==  Block was alloc'd at
==4185==    at 0x4C2B145: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:333)
==4185==    by 0x4A85AE: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:104)
==4185==    by 0x4A788F: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:351)
==4185==    by 0x4A6A01: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, md::sym::Registry*, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry> const&) (shared_ptr_base.h:499)
==4185==    by 0x4A59FB: std::__shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry> const&) (shared_ptr_base.h:957)
==4185==    by 0x4A44C9: std::shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry>::shared_ptr<std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry> const&) (shared_ptr.h:316)
==4185==    by 0x4A353D: std::shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry> std::allocate_shared<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>>(std::allocator<md::sym::Registry> const&) (shared_ptr.h:598)
==4185==    by 0x4A1FD8: std::shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry> std::make_shared<md::sym::Registry>() (shared_ptr.h:614)
==4185==    by 0x4A02E0: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) (base.cpp:10)
==4185==    by 0x4A034B: _GLOBAL__sub_I_base.cpp (base.cpp:206)
==4185==    by 0x4B7BDC: __libc_csu_init (in /media/hdd/work/metadiff/metadiff-core/build/try)
==4185==    by 0x78D9E54: (below main) (libc-start.c:246)
==4185== 
==4185== 
==4185== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4185==     in use at exit: 96 bytes in 1 blocks
==4185==   total heap usage: 10,725 allocs, 10,724 frees, 688,288 bytes allocated
==4185== 
==4185== 96 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==4185==    at 0x4C2B145: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:333)
==4185==    by 0x4A85AE: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:104)
==4185==    by 0x4A788F: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:351)
==4185==    by 0x4A6A01: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, md::sym::Registry*, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry> const&) (shared_ptr_base.h:499)
==4185==    by 0x4A59FB: std::__shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry> const&) (shared_ptr_base.h:957)
==4185==    by 0x4A44C9: std::shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry>::shared_ptr<std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry> const&) (shared_ptr.h:316)
==4185==    by 0x4A353D: std::shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry> std::allocate_shared<md::sym::Registry, std::allocator<md::sym::Registry>>(std::allocator<md::sym::Registry> const&) (shared_ptr.h:598)
==4185==    by 0x4A1FD8: std::shared_ptr<md::sym::Registry> std::make_shared<md::sym::Registry>() (shared_ptr.h:614)
==4185==    by 0x5D28A1C: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) (base.cpp:10)
==4185==    by 0x5D28A87: _GLOBAL__sub_I_base.cpp (base.cpp:206)
==4185==    by 0x4010139: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:78)
==4185==    by 0x4010222: call_init (dl-init.c:36)
==4185==    by 0x4010222: _dl_init (dl-init.c:126)
==4185== 
==4185== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4185==    definitely lost: 96 bytes in 1 blocks
==4185==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4185==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4185==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4185==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4185== 
==4185== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
```

The way I initialize the static variable is I have it declared in a header file as:

```
extern std::shared_ptr<Registry> const registry;
```

And a single cpp file has:

```
std::shared_ptr<Registry> const registry = std::make_shared<Registry>();
```

Also the `Registry` class looks like this:

```
class Registry:  public std::enable_shared_from_this<Registry>{
        public:
            /** The total number of ids already used */
            I total_ids;
            /** A register for all variables which are result of a floor operation */
            std::vector <std::pair<I, std::pair < Polynomial, Polynomial>>> floor_registry;
            /** A register for all variables which are result of a ceil operation */
            std::vector <std::pair<I, std::pair < Polynomial, Polynomial>>> ceil_registry;

            Registry(): total_ids(0){};
            /** Some functions */
        }
```

For further info, this all is build into a static library to which I'm building against my program. Would anyone have even only hints on pointers on what could be causing this leak or what the error means?

Comment: I don't think this is actually a leak. It's a single value that's simply not returned until after/during your leak detection.

Comment: I think it is somehow, cause I have a static shared_ptr to another class, and that one does not raise the SIGABRT or the valgrind leak.

Comment: This is not a memory leak. "Invalid read of size 4/Address 0x7c95ab8 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 96 free'd" indicates a bug in the code. Use after free/delete.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik but that would be very weird as the error is raise literally after the the return of the main function. My code has no "background" running, so for some reason it is trying to access the registry after the end of the program?

Comment: @Belov - I'll happily demonstrate a sample function that craps all over the heap, returns fine to the parent, only to have the parent crash at some point later, when it attempts to use the utterly corrupted heap. Just because the program crashes at a particular point doesn't mean that's where the bug is. Welcome to C++.

Comment: Do you have any idea what could be causing, does it mean that I'm freeing the registry earlier or what?